# How to print multiple values from multiple array/list with string in front of first output only and comma separation between values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to have my output formatted as 'Mode = 15, 59'.  I'm fairly new to Python so there could be a completely easier way I'm just not aware of yet or how to google the question better.  Thank you for your help.

**Please see code below:**

```
import numpy as np

dataset = [15, 21, 59, 15, 37, 59, 11, 41]
dataset.sort()

print(dataset)

unique = np.unique(dataset)
print(unique)

testing = []
for d in unique:
    testing.append(dataset.count(d))
print(testing)

combine = np.column_stack((unique,testing))
print(combine)

g = max(testing)

for i, j in combine:
    if j == g:
        #print('{}'.format(i), end='')
        #print("Mode = %s" %(i),end='')
        print('Mode =', i, end='')
        #print(i, end='')
```

**Output:**

```
[11, 15, 15, 21, 37, 41, 59, 59]
[11 15 21 37 41 59]
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[[11  1]
 [15  2]
 [21  1]
 [37  1]
 [41  1]
 [59  2]]
Mode = 15Mode = 59
```

Comment: create a new/empty list, then if ```j==g``` add j to the list. finally print "Mode" concatenated with the elements of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
combine = [
    [11, 1],
    [15, 2],
    [21, 1],
    [37, 1],
    [41, 1],
    [59, 2],
]
g = 2

modes = []

for i, j in combine:
    if j == g:
        modes.append(str(i))

print('Mode =', ', '.join(modes))
```

Comment: Showing him how to fish would have been better than giving him the fish

Comment: Your solution worked, except the output is:  'Mode = 15 \n Mode = 15, 59'.  Not sure why it's outputting the initial 15 first?  I'll give it a go from here and see if I can figure it out.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tested adding the i.values manually to the modes array and got the proper result (modes.append(str(15)) and modes.append(str(59))).  Something in the for loop seems to be storing an extra value or I may have stored a previous array incorrectly.

Comment: @44086e It sounds like when you copied my code you indented the print so that it was part of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `collections.Counter`. 
Ref: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter
To get mode:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

dataset = [15, 21, 59, 15, 37, 59, 11, 41]

#dict of format - key: no_of_occurences

dataset_counter=Counter(dataset)

print(dataset_counter)

#above reversed i.e. no_of_occurences: keys sorted by no_of_occurences

dataset_counter=dict((k, list(el[0] for el in v)) for k,v in groupby(sorted(dataset_counter.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True), lambda x: x[1]))

mode=list(dataset_counter.values())[0]
print(f"Mode={mode}")

print(dataset_counter)
```

Outputs:

```py
Counter({15: 2, 59: 2, 21: 1, 37: 1, 11: 1, 41: 1})
Mode=[15, 59]
{2: [15, 59], 1: [21, 37, 11, 41]}
```